# ubuntu 16.04 で can't set locale を解消するには?

Tags: ubuntu, locale, openssh

今、 ubuntu/xenial64 を指定して、 vagrant で、 virtualbox の仮想マシンを起動しました。 vagrant ssh を行うと、次のエラーメッセージが表示されます。

```
manpath: can't set the locale; make sure $LC_* and $LANG are correct
```

上記はワーニング的で、表示されたからといってシェルが起動しないわけでもなく、少し触ってみても、得に何か取り立てて問題がおこっている訳ではないのですが、ワーニングならば、わざわざ罠にはまる前に解消しておきたいと考えました。

質問: 上記エラーメッセージを解消するには、何をやったらいいのでしょうか?

Comment: メッセージを素直に読むと`$LC_`で始まる環境変数とか`$LANG`が変になっている感じで、言語が正しく設定されていないように見えますがその辺りは確認済でしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mac から vagrant ssh していたのですが、 mac の ssh が

```
SendEnv LANG LC_*
```

する設定になっていて、そのためにローカルの `LC_*` 系の環境変数が送られてしまい、 ubuntu
 のシステムに入っていないロケールの値が指定され、おかしくなっていました。

mac の `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` にて、上記設定行をコメントアウトすることで、解決しました。

Answer (score 0):

英語版SOにも同様のやり取りがありました。
[manpath: can't set the locale; make sure $LC_* and $LANG are correct - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45995530/manpath-cant-set-the-locale-make-sure-lc-and-lang-are-correct)

日本語環境に置き換えると

```
sudo locale-gen "ja_JP.UTF-8"
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

また、`/etc/default/locale`をエディタで開いて`LC_ALL="ja_JP.UTF-8"`を追記または編集後、念のためマシンにログインし直してみてください。